# Show that the sum of the oscilations is less or equal to $f(b)-f(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, monotone-functions, bounded-variation

I want to show the following:

> Let $ f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function.If $ x_1,\ldots,x_k\in[a,b]$
>   are different, show that $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k o(f,x_i) < f(b) - f(a).$$

My attempt:

Since $f$ is increasing we have that:

$$f(a)<f(x_1)<f(x_2)< \ldots <f(b).$$

Therefore for each $i=1, \ldots, k$ and for all $\delta$,

$$M(f,x_i, \delta)< f(b) \quad \text{and} \quad m(f,x_i, \delta)> f(a)$$

and then in each point:

$$o(f,x_i) < f(b) - f(a).$$

The thing is that I don't know how to proceed with the sum. Can someone help me to complete this proof?

Answer (score 2):

We should assume that $f$ is not constant at $[a,b]-\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$.

Choose $a=y_0\le x_1<y_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n\le y_n=b$, then $O(f,x_i)\le f(y_i)-f(y_{i-1})$. Add these inequalities together to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot eclipse sun, but which are the exceptional cases ?

Comment: That is when $a=x_1$ or $b=x_n$.

Comment: Mmmm well I dont see that part :(

Comment: I dont think that the exceptional cases could change your above proof, well Is a special case and that is all right ?

Comment: Yes, I have edited it, so there is no exceptional cases any more.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, the inequality  O(f,xi)≤f(yi)−f(yi−1), is becuase of what I have explained in my post right?

Comment: Yes, if I understood your explanation correctly.

Comment: good, now, the intercalation with the $y_i$, is just a way to put the points in $[a,b]$ or is something more deep than that?

Comment: Since you have asked for more information, I'd like to tell you this proposition leads to a simple fact that monotonic function is of bounded variation. And there is a converse, which is much more difficult, that any function of bounded variation is the difference of two increasing functions.

Comment: Well, is that what you using in the above proof?

Comment: Not really. I just estimate the value of $O(f,x_i)$. That's why I introduce $y_i$'s.

Comment: then the $y_i$'s are only numbers between the $x_i$'s?

Comment: They are chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: only with the inequalities condition right?,and we can assume that $f$ is not constant because if it is it would be continous and the oscilation is 0 rght?

Comment: Yes. But I assume $f$ is not constant because you want to prove a strict inequality. Consider a step function, for example.

Comment: Ok and the other question, thanks